# Install official Europe ICS ROM on Optimus 2x outside Europe

Tags: updates, rom-flashing, lg-optimus-2x

Now that ICS is available to users in Europe for LG Optimus 2x (p990): I have a p990 but it was purchased in India. Can I download the ROM for Europe and flash the same on my phone? Will  it work? Will it give any issues for network connectivity? Or do I wait till the official ICS ROM is released for India?

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems, likely you'll just need to set up an APN for the network you're using.

Comment: you can get official un-official and AOSP based roms (CM) for the XDA discussion here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1002 the AIO tool should help you install EU roms on your device
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2020737